# How do I make ImageOps.fit not crop?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

How do I get `ImageOps.fit(source28x32, (128, 128))` to fit without cropping off the top/bottom/sides? Do I really have to find the aspect, resize accordingly so the enlarged version does not exceed 128x128, and then add border pixels (or center the image in a 128x128 canvas)? Mind you that the source can be of any ratio, the 28x32 is just an example.

source image (28x32)

[image: source image]

fitted image (128x128)

[image: fitted image]

This is my attempt so far, not particularly elegant

```
def fit(im):
    size = 128

    x, y = im.size
    ratio = float(x) / float(y)
    if x > y:
        x = size
        y = size * 1 / ratio
    else:
        y = size
        x = size * ratio
    x, y = int(x), int(y)
    im = im.resize((x, y))

    new_im = Image.new('L', (size, size), 0)
    new_im.paste(im, ((size - x) / 2, (size - y) / 2))
    return new_im
```

New fitted image

[image: new fitted]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the function implemented in both `PIL` and `cv2`. The input can be of any size; the function finds the scale needed to fit the largest edge to the desired width, and then puts it onto a black square image of the desired width.

*In PIL*

```
def resize_PIL(im, output_edge):
    scale = output_edge / max(im.size)
    new = Image.new(im.mode, (output_edge, output_edge), (0, 0, 0))
    paste = im.resize((int(im.width * scale), int(im.height * scale)), resample=Image.NEAREST)
    new.paste(paste, (0, 0))
    return new
```

*In cv2*

```
def resize_cv2(im, output_edge):
    scale = output_edge / max(im.shape[:2])
    new = np.zeros((output_edge, output_edge, 3), np.uint8)
    paste = cv2.resize(im, None, fx=scale, fy=scale, interpolation=cv2.INTER_NEAREST)
    new[:paste.shape[0], :paste.shape[1], :] = paste
    return new
```

With a desired width of 128:

[image] →
[image]

[image] →
[image]

*Not shown: these functions work on images larger than the desired size*

Answer (score 0):

This works pretty good to fit the image to size you want while filling in the rest with black space

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
def fit(im, width):
  border = int((max(im.width, im.height) - min(im.width, im.height))/2)
  im = ImageOps.expand(im, border)
  im = ImageOps.fit(im, (width, width))
  return im
```